# What does "Please find the attached for the completed application form" mean?

Tags: meaning

I was filling an online application form, then after filling out and clicking "submit this information", the following message appeared:

> Please find the attached for the completed application form.

So I'm wondering what this means and does it mean that something went wrong that I should start all over again?

Comment: while this sentence isn't quite grammatical, what it means is that you can download  a completed version of the form so that you can print it. It's telling you that a *filled-in* version of the form is available as an attachment of some sort.

Comment: They are confirming your submission using dated wording, but you don't have to resubmit. The key phrasing is "completed application form." *Find the attached* probably means look below at whatever we wrote.

Comment: What happened then? Did you get to see or download the completed form? If so, then it's almost certainly submitted correctly. Otherwise, since it was evidently devised by someone with questionable grasp of English, it's hard to tell what might have happened.